# Using a h1, h2 keywords as a list and not as part of the content

Tags: seo, keywords, tags

I've noticed some people using their targeted keywords as a simple list e.g. on the footer and not in the content.
E.g. using

```
<h1>Keyword1</h1>, <h2>Keyword2</h2>, <h2>Keyword3</h2>
```

in footer and showing it in all pages.
Is this practical and does it effect SEO in a good way?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you are abusing HTML tags for the sake of manipulating the search results. This is one way to hurt your SEO efforts. Stop focusing on search engines and focus on users. If you got creative like this with content your rankings would almost certainly improve.

Comment: What cracks me up about this is that header tags are very nearly useless for SEO. Google, for example, will never match against a header tag and header tags are only good for topical analysis assuming that they make semantic sense which, in this case, they would not. This is more keyword match nonsense. Do not do this. It is a seriously useless tactic!